# Do I need to spend extra for a special oven light bulb?

Tags: electrical, oven, light-bulb

My oven light went out and I need a new bulb. That would be something like [this one](https://www.frigidaireapplianceparts.com/PartDetail/Light-Bulb/316538904/4959061), which is over $20 for a single light bulb! I understand that the oven gets very hot and so maybe some kind of special bulb is needed, but surely it could be cheaper than that.

Or can it?

Comment: I have fixed fridges, washing machines, dishwashers, ovens, cookers but only replaced one of those bulbs - they last… But have you checked other suppliers?

Comment: Just to give you a comparison - in the EU, incandescent lamps are banned except for special purposes, one of which is ovens. Still, you can get one for  €1.50: https://www.dm.de/mueller-licht-backofenlampe-15w-90lm-e14-agl-p4018412321251.html. Don't try to use this, it's 240V, but I'm certain you can get one at a similar price in the US.

Comment: Related : [Are there LED lamps available for ovens?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/222187/41369)

Comment: Clearly not, but how much time and imagination can you invest?

This very week, I drove nearly an hour each way to collect a microwave oven "free for recycling…"… Ignoring my own time, the cost of the mileage might just have justified the expedition

Perhaps less obviously, why not read the specs of the failed bulb, then throw them at your chosen search engine?

Answer (score 34):

That is **pure profiteering** for folks silly enough to go to the appliance parts store for a light bulb.

Far less expensive at a hardware store, or many other normal stores with lightbulbs. You need an "Appliance bulb" of the normal old incandescent flavor. Not a newfangled LED refrigerator bulb. Incandescent bulbs are perfectly happy at oven temperatures, and the "appliance" version adds a bit of extra support against vibration, etc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132987/discussion-on-answer-by-ecnerwal-do-i-need-to-spend-20-on-an-oven-light-bulb).

Answer (score 6):

Do you follow any of the warnings we give around here about the danger of 3-prong (groundless) range receptacles... and you think "Why does a 240V oven need 120V?"

***The oven light***.

That's right.  The dangerous setup is *solely so consumers can use ANY random 120V incandescent bulb* they buy by the dozen (back in the day when everyone used incandescents and they were four for a buck).

After all, if we were going to make consumers buy **special** bulbs for ovens, we could just make them 240V bulbs, and then dispense with that darned neutral wire!

So yes. Standard incandescent bulb is fine.  If you know the academic meaning of the word "incandescent", it means they are "creatures of heat" and love hot environments.

Halogens, even more so.  Real incandescents are nearly gone from the US market; the "traditional" bulbs sold in stores are actually halogen (a kind of incandescent) that uses an inner "tube" containing a VERY, VERY hot lamp, and an outer globe just to keep your finger oil off the halogen tube.

But never use LED or CFL - those must run *cool* and their housings are made of plastics which will melt in the oven.

Comment: Let's move the whole debate about 120 vs 240v to [this Meta](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1659/55930)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132988/discussion-on-answer-by-harper-reinstate-monica-do-i-need-to-spend-20-on-an-o).

Answer (score 6):

No, any 40W incandescent that is similar size and base will work just fine. I would buy these ones from [Amazon](https://amzn.to/3eZQ5aB). Replacement and a spare for $5.

[image]

Comment: Oddly, they show a refrigerator in the top right icon - somewhere it's actually much better to use a cool LED rather than an incandescent which will dump heat into the fridge.  Curious that they elected to not use an oven or range for that icon...

Comment: @J... I agree. I even got away with an LED lamp in a gas clothes dryer. Probably has something to do with making money rather than recommending the very best product.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one locally, go to a dollar store (like Dollar Tree, 99 Cents Only Store, etc.) and get an Appliance Bulb.

I bought one at Dollar Tree recently. Cost $1 or so.